# Change Video position while playback

Tags: android

Is there any way on Android to dynamically change position of VideoView or SurfaceView while playing video?
I've tried to use view animators, Surface.setPosition(), View.layout(), push Surface view with ralated LinearLayout with bigger weight( this approach helps sometimes and i see that video jumps to new position while playing but i need smooth moving.) and nothing happens until video ends.

(Checked on Emulator (2.2) and Nexus One  - results are the same)

Answer (score 0):

Test it on actual device, mine also didnt work on emulator but worked on device